# How can I create an empty file in Linux available to all users?

Tags: linux, file-management

As the admin, how can I create a file that will be available to all users?

Answer (score 1):

`touch filename` to create it and then :

`chmod 444 filename` to give only read permissions to everyone, or

`chmod 644 filename`: same as before except the owner can write to it, or

`chmod 755 filename`: owner can read, write and execute it. Members in the user group and others can read and execute the file but cannot write to it, or

`chmod 777 filename`: Anyone can read, write and execute the file.

Comment: Not "chmod 777 filename" ? Only "read-only" access? Why that?

Comment: @duDE Changed my answer.

Comment: It's a shame the OP didn't put precisely what they wanted from "how can I create an empty file... available to all users"... there's confusion over "readable by all users" and "readable/editable by all users"...!

Comment: @BigChris You can vote to close as "unclear ..." ;)

Comment: Now it looks nice, +1 ! :)